# Find file and commit with searched string in git

Tags: git

I can find all commits that added or removed the string "whatever":

```
git log -S "whatever" --source --all
```

However, this finds commit only. I would also like to get a file when this addition/deletion took place.

Comment: You should try to use `git log -L :specific_function_name:fileInWhichTheFunctionResides` if you want to see the history of the file itself

Answer (score 0):

With different options to [`git log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) you can see lists of files in every commit (`--name-only`), add/delete statistics (`--stat`), diff (`--patch`) or diff with statistics (`--patch-with-stat`).